# How to use the functions of the students to order their averages?

Tags: python, sorting

Here is the question:

> Use the program functions to get the name, surname and 4 marks for 5 students and finally print out the names of the students in order of their average.

I wrote the functions, so I can get the averages of each student, but I do not know how to sort the name of the students.

```
_firstname = []
_familiname = []
_scores = []

def student1():
    input('Please enter the firstname:')
    input('Please enter the familiname:')
    for i in range(0, 4):
        scores = int(input('Please enter the scores:'))
        _scores.append(scores)
    b = sum(_scores)
    avg1 = b/4
    print('avg is',avg1)

def student2():
    input('Please enter the firstname:')
    input('Please enter the familiname:')
    for i in range(0, 4):
        scores = int(input('Please enter the scores:'))
        _scores.append(scores)
    b = sum(_scores)
    avg2 = b/4
    print('avg is',avg2)

def student3():
    input('Please enter the firstname:')
    input('Please enter the familiname:')
    for i in range(0, 4):
        scores = int(input('Please enter the scores:'))
        _scores.append(scores)
    b = sum(_scores)
    avg3 = b/4
    print('avg is',avg3)

def student4():
    input('Please enter the firstname:')
    input('Please enter the familiname:')
    for i in range(0, 4):
        scores = int(input('Please enter the scores:'))
        _scores.append(scores)
    b = sum(_scores)
    avg4 = b/4
    print('avg is',avg4)

def student5():
    input('Please enter the firstname:')
    input('Please enter the familiname:')
    for i in range(0, 4):
        scores = int(input('Please enter the scores:'))
        _scores.append(scores)
    b = sum(_scores)
    avg5 = b/4
    print('avg is',avg5)

student1()
student2()
student3()
student4()
student5()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is obviously homework, but heres a start:

```py
scores = {90:'best', 80:'good', 60:'ehh'}

ordered_scores = sorted(scores.keys())
print('ordered_scores', ordered_scores)

for score in ordered_scores:
    print('score', score, 'student', scores[score])
```

gives you

```
ordered_scores [60, 80, 90]
score 60 student ehh
score 80 student good
score 90 student best
```

See if you can change the order of the sort. Good luck!

Comment: The scores were in a list. I suggested using a dict to preserve the pairing of scores and names.

Sorting just the list of scores would decouple the indexing of the scores and the names.

Comment: That was valuable feedback martineau. Thank you sincerely.